# Using Prefix Lists in Security Groups

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

if I was to use the AWS documentation for creating Security Groups using CloudFormation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html), it appears lacking in what I am trying to achieve. There are plenty of examples where egress rules can be configured to use a CIDR value as the destination which is all very well and good.

But what I am trying to achieve is to use a prefix-list id (pl-112233) as a network destination

For example:

```
    "SecurityGroupEgress" : [{
        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
        "FromPort" : 80,
        "ToPort" : 80,
        "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" # using prefix list example pl-112233
    }]
```

Unfortunately I cannot locate any support for this requirement and I want to understand if other's have met this difficulty. I should point out that these prefix lists pre-exist and don't need to be created as part of this CloudFormation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup Egress - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html), it would seem that you can use:

```json
 "SecurityGroupEgress" : [{
        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
        "FromPort" : 80,
        "ToPort" : 80,
        "DestinationPrefixListId" : "pl-112233"
    }]
```